# Triangular multiplication table in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program in java that would create a 10 (row) by 15 (column) triangular multiplication table for an assignment. In the assignment we have to use constants IMAX= 10 and JMAX=15. I have attached a picture below of what the table should look like. I've gotten the jist of the table but am having trouble trying to stop the math and row 10 and also adding a border in the column numbers. Help would be appreciated.
Also to do this problem, we are permitted to use if/else statements, for loop and/or while loop

[Multiplication table link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2De6z.png)

```
public class Question2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final int IMAX= 15, JMAX=10;    

        for (int i = 1; i <= JMAX; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print( i + "  ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("--------------------------------------------------------" );
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 1; i <= IMAX; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(i*j + " " );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }           
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int IMAX= 15, JMAX=10;

        System.out.print("   |");
        for (int i = 1; i <= JMAX; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-4d", i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("--------------------------------------------------------" );
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 1; i <= IMAX; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-3d|", i);
            for (int j = 1; j <= i && j <=JMAX; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%-4d", i*j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } 

}
```

Comment: I tried to use the printf method before but any time I try to use it I get a an error stating "the method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)"

Comment: You are in a older version of java. try using this
System.out.printf("%-3s ", new Object[] {i*j} );

Comment: It's still giving me an error saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to object"... is the only way to fix problem getting an updated version?

Comment: Try this... System.out.printf("%-3s ", new Object[]{new Integer(i*j)} );

Comment: yes it worked now, thank you. However, now when I run the program, the initial column from 1-10 only appears once. I need it to appear once as a display column just like the first row, and then as the first column of calculation itself as shown in the picture I attached. Can you help me with that also

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No need to allocate a new Object every time. Try "%-4d", not "%-4s". d means Integral decimal.

Comment: I used new Object  and new Integer because OP was in a older version of java where printf with variable arg and autoboxing is not supported. And I dont think "%-4d" and "%-4s" matters, it is going to be converted to string anyway @LppEdd

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int IMAX = 15, JMAX = 10;
        System.out.print("   |");
        for (int i = 1; i <= JMAX; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 1; i <= IMAX; i++) {
            if (i < 10) {
                System.out.print(i + "  |");
            } else {
                System.out.print(i + " |");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(i * j + " ");
                if (j == JMAX) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this. Do you know how to add the border thing in the first column, where is states the value and | as shown in the picture I attached. I have been trying to figure out how to add that into the table but can't seem to do it without ruining the rest of th code.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is multiplication table in java

```
import java.util.*;
public class table
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=1; i <=12; i++)
        System.out.println(a+ "    x    " +i + "   =   " +a*i);
    }
}
```

You can change the variable names whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in millions different ways!

```
public class Test
{
   private static final int ROWS = 15;
   private static final int COLS = 10;

   public static final void main(final String... args) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++) {
         if (i < 1) {
            System.out.printf("%5s", " | ");

            for (int k = 1; k <= COLS; k++) {
               System.out.printf("%-4d", k);
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("____________________________________________");
            continue;
         }

         System.out.printf("%5s", i + " | ");

         for (int j = 1; j <= i && j <= COLS; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%-4d", i * j);
         }

         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help & time! Can I just ask what exactly this %-4s and %5s is? What does this function do and what is the difference between 3 and 4 and 5 etc..

Comment: Briefly, 3, 4 or 5 are the total number of characters displayed. - indicate that the given parameter must be left aligned. s indicate the parameter is a string.
They're Formatters. Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax